# Core Animation interactive flip transition like playing card with front and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

I'm trying to recreate Apple's `UIView transitionFromView:ToView:` with Core Animation so I can use it with an interactive view controller transition. It's almost there, but I can't get the "to" view controller's view to show up on the back of the card.

```
CATransform3D inRotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
inRotation.m34 = -0.02;
CATransform3D outRotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-0.01, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
outRotation.m34 = -0.02;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0
                            relativeDuration:0.5
                                  animations:^{
                                      fromViewController.view.layer.transform = inRotation;
                                  }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5
                            relativeDuration:0.5
                                  animations:^{
                                      toViewController.view.layer.transform = outRotation;
                                  }];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
}];
```

I think I need to swap the two views (`fromViewController.view` and `toViewController.view`) somehow halfway through the transition but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most idiomatic way to do this but I have a working solution:

```
[fromViewController.view.layer setDoubleSided:NO];
[toViewController.view.layer setDoubleSided:NO];

[container insertSubview:toViewController.view belowSubview:fromViewController.view];

CGFloat h = 0.0001;

CATransform3D initialToRotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI - h, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
initialToRotation.m34 = -0.002;
[toViewController.view.layer setTransform:initialToRotation];

CATransform3D initialFromRotation = CATransform3DIdentity;
initialFromRotation.m34 = -0.002;
[fromViewController.view.layer setTransform:initialFromRotation];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [fromViewController.view.layer setTransform:CATransform3DRotate(initialFromRotation, M_PI - h, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)];
    [toViewController.view.layer setTransform:CATransform3DRotate(initialToRotation, M_PI + h, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    BOOL wasCanceled = [transitionContext transitionWasCancelled];
    if (wasCanceled) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:NO];
    } else {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
    }
}];
```

The important thing is that both the front and back need to rotate together, and the front needs to be rotated in advance of the transition. You set up your view hierarchy in the container view but the transformation code is called on the viewControllers' views directly. Also, CoreAnimation doesn't seem to have any notion of clockwise or counter-clockwise, so you need to rotate either just *over* or just *short of* pi radians in order to ensure the right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that does this. Here is what we use for this project. It isn't CoreAnimation but gets the job done.

```
-(void)configureView{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];


    _contentsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0, 0)];
    _contentsView.backgroundColor = RGB(GRAY_BACKGROUND);
    _contentsView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    _contentsView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [_contentsView.layer setBorderColor: [RGB(DARK_GRAY) CGColor]];
    [_contentsView.layer setBorderWidth: .5];
    [_contentsView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
    [self.view addSubview:_contentsView];

    CardFrontController *front = [CardFrontController new];
    [front.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [_contentsView addSubview:front.view];

    _backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0, 0)];

    // load the back of the card
    cardBack = [CardBackController new];
    [_backView addSubview:cardBack.view];

}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    // animate the card flipping
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    if (!_review) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    } else {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // now stuff that we don't need to animate
    if (!_review) {
        [_contentsView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:_backView];
    }
    else {
        [_backView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view addSubview:_contentsView];
    }

    _review = !_review;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work with an interactive transition. You need to use one of the block-based UIView animation methods so you can't use UIView animation transitions.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that all the important info is in that final sentence and it doesn't make sense. "As you apply the rotation to both the front and back layer they will change which layer is visible. Note: rotate the front to π degrees and the back to 2π so that it completes it rotation and faces you."

Comment: @jefflovejapan i believe he is referring to `M_PI`. Take a look at http://blog.radi.ws/post/11484924164/flipping-with-proper-perspective-distortion-in-core UIView does have block methods for completion.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inRotation` should have been with `M_PI_2` (or `-M_PI_2`) instead of `M_PI`. The following solution is closer to your original code and it avoids your hacky workaround of *just over or just short of pi* by performing two quarter rotations:

```swift
func flip(_ flipToFront: Bool) {
    let fromView: UIView = flipToFront ? toViewController.view! : fromViewController.view!
    let toView: UIView = flipToFront ? fromViewController.view! : toViewController.view!

    fromView.superview!.insertSubview(fromView, belowSubview: toView)

    var initialToRotation: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0, 1, 0)
    initialToRotation.m34 = -0.004
    toView.layer.transform = initialToRotation

    var initialFromRotation: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
    initialFromRotation.m34 = -0.004
    fromView.layer.transform = initialFromRotation

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(initialFromRotation, .pi / (flipToFront ? 2 : -2), 0, 1, 0)
            toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(initialToRotation, .pi / (flipToFront ? -2 : 2), 0, 1, 0)
        })
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(initialFromRotation, .pi, 0, 1, 0)
            toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(initialToRotation, .pi, 0, 1, 0)
        })
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Where I previously set:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fromViewController.view.layer.isDoubleSided = false
    toViewController.view.layer.isDoubleSided = false
}
```